# How to handle states when logged in (Ionic, Firebase, AngularJS)?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, ionic-framework

I am building an app in Ionic and have started to dig into the Firebase Authentication method. So far I have managed to setup a Login through Twitter properly (I can login and logout).

However, how do I set the states of the ionic framework such that only specific states (and thus pages) are shown when Logged in and others when Logged out? The code I have so far is shown below.

Ideally I would have something like a variable:

```
AuthRequired: true
```

How do you do this and what is it called?

**app.js**

```
   // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'firebase', 'firebase.utils', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'starter.config', 'starter.auth'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, Auth, $rootScope) {


  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });



  //stateChange event
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      if (toState.authRequired && !Auth.isAuthenticated()){ //Assuming the AuthService holds authentication logic
        // User isn’t authenticated
        $state.transitionTo("login");
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }
  });





})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl',
        authRequired: true
      },
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl',
           authRequired: true
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl',
           authRequired: true
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.friends', {
      url: '/friends',
      views: {
        'tab-friends': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-friends.html',
          controller: 'FriendsCtrl',
           authRequired: true
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.friend-detail', {
      url: '/friend/:friendId',
      views: {
        'tab-friends': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/friend-detail.html',
          controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl',
           authRequired: true
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl',
           authRequired: true
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.example', {
    url: '/example',
    views: {
      'tab-example': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-example.html',
        controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
           authRequired: true
      }
    }
  })


  .state('tab.overview', {
    url: '/overview',
    views: {
      'tab-overview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-overview.html',
        controller: 'OverviewCtrl',
           authRequired: true
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'tab-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
           authRequired: true
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


    <!-- firebase and simple login -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>


    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>



  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).


    -->

    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use the ui router or the official ngRouter? For myself, I use the ui router and in each state, I am able to save custom data like a boolean named "public", which decides if the corresponding state needs authentication or not. I can give you more detailed information if you want something like that.

Comment: Hi Himmet. To be honest I dont know, I think the standard one that comes with the Ionic Framework. Yes please share your methods!

Comment: I'm able to get the accepted answer to work. One difference in my code is that I have the 'authRequired' as a property of the state and not nested in the state's view. Otherwise, it looked to me that you'd need to modify the 'toState.authRequire' to check inside of the toState.view

Comment: Can you show your code in a seperate answer? Thanks

Comment: [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) and [generator-angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire/) use similar patterns, adding a decorator on the $routeProvider service to create authenticated routes. Adapting them to ui-router is a 30 minute exercise.

Answer (score 15):

You are almost there. All you need is to ensure your states are marked appropriate with the custom property 'AuthRequired' and listen for $stateChangeStart event to check for authentication. This event  fires each time you move with in the application.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, AuthService) {
      //ionic init code    

      //stateChange event
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      if (toState.authRequired && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()){ //Assuming the AuthService holds authentication logic
        // User isn’t authenticated
        $state.transitionTo("login");
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }
    });
}

.state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl',
        authRequired: true
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl',
          authRequired: true
        }
      }
    })
```

The best place to have $stateChangeStart event handler would be the app run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not get it exactly where and how to put the stateChangeStart?

Comment: @AMG stateChange event handler has to be placed in the run function where you initialize the ionic. run function is the closest to main method in angular, which gets executed when the app is loaded.  I updated the code for you

Comment: Thanks for the update. It does not seem to work for me since I have my states in the .config. The AuthService is Auth?

Comment: Basically, now the app still runs and everything, but I can still go to the page dash even when logged out... I have updated my Question with my current code.

Comment: Hello. How does your service look like? the isAuthenticated()?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. The assumption with isAuthenticated() method was that it holds all the auth logic and let us know if the user is authenticated or not. In your case you will have the firebase auth implemented through the AuthService and expose a method to track if the user is authenticated.

Comment: This is a good solution. There's a working implementation of this strategy, using Angular + Firebase, in the [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) project.

Comment: @Kato. Agreed, but it is not synchronized with the Ionic Framework, there it gets problematic. Do you have other snippets?

Comment: @Karthik: I still havent figured it out. Could you give me the full example?

Comment: It is a great solution, solves the purpose. Don't know why it is not the accepted answer. Looks like OP is expecting someone to code for him.

Comment: I tried to implement this as Karthik has written and always have toState.authRequired undefined... I was trying to check it like this: $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log('toState: ' + toState.authRequired);
  });

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that yours! Take a look how I solved it!

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic','firebase', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services','app.filters',])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {//
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  //stateChange event
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (toState.authRequired && !user){ //Assuming the AuthService holds authentication logic
      // User isn’t authenticated
      $state.transitionTo("login");
      event.preventDefault(); 
    }
  });
  // Initialize Firebase Here

})
```

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ionicUIRouter'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider  

  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })

 .state('menu', {
    url: '/menu',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    abstract:true,
    controller: 'menuCtrl'
  })

  .state('menu.dash', {
    url: '/contas',
    templateUrl: 'templates/dash.html',
    controller: 'contasCtrl',
    authRequired: true
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To succeed read the value using:

```
toState.authRequired
```

Please move `authRequired: true` inside of `.state`  instead of `views`.