# Different tabs for different user roles using $rootScope in .state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What Im aiming is that I will have different tabs layout for different users
like patient and doctors

in my controller, I store the logged user in **$rootScope.currentUser** like this

```
$auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {
           return $http.get(CONSTANTS.LINK+'/authenticate/user');
        }, function(data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error Logging in',
            template: 'Invalid Credentials'
            });
            alertPopup.then(function(res) {
            });
        }).then(function(response) {
                var user = JSON.stringify(response.data.user);
                localStorage.setItem('user', user);
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.user;
                $state.go('tabs.home');
            });;
```

Now this is my app.js. Nothing happens. am i Doing it right?
The **$rootscope.currentUser** is also returning *undefined* when i try **console.log($rootScope.currentUser)**;

```
.state('tabs', {
        url: '/tab',
        templateUrl: function ($rootScope) {
          if($rootScope.currentUser.role == 'Patient') {
            return 'templates/tabs.html';
          } else if ($rootScope.currentUser.role == 'Doctor') {
            return 'templates/tabs-doctors.html';
          }
        },
        abstract: true,
    })
```

Comment: I kinda think you're approaching this all wrong. What I'm thinking is you should create different states for doctor and patient, and then in your .run(or ready)function check the user and use $state.go. I believe this could take you in right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907670/how-to-handle-states-when-logged-in-ionic-firebase-angularjs

Comment: You can also refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429055/angularjs-ui-router-load-template-and-controller-based-on-user-role also one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047884/angular-ui-router-to-accomplish-a-conditional-view

Comment: @Marko thank you sir! I will check this out

Comment: The ui-router doesn't use the $injector service for the templateURL function. It invokes that function with a `params` argument. For more information, see [ui-router $stateProvider API Reference](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider). It is erroneous to expect `$rootScope` to be injected into that function.

Comment: Post answer when you get working example if you want, i'll upvote you. Might need sometimes for me/someone

Comment: @Marko, I posted my solution :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was storing the user data in local storage when he logs in, I used that data to check the role of the user.

```
.state('tabs', {
        url: '/tab',
        templateUrl: function () {
          var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
          role = user.role;
          if(role == 'Patient') {
            return 'templates/tabs.html';
          } else if (role == 'Doctor') {
            return 'templates/tabs2.html';
          } else {
            return 'templates/tabs.html';
          }
        },
        abstract: true,
    })
```